# Ajax call accepts json but controller returns html

Tags: jquery, ajax, get, jsonresult, asp.net-mvc-controller

So, I have been using $.getJson() successfully to grab data.  In this instance, I needed to synchronously grab data from the server, so I used:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    async: false,
    url: "/Mapping/MappingExists?id=" + id,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        alert("SUCCESS");
        EnableAll("disableElement");
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("ERROR");
        result = true;
    }
});
```

The controller is:

```
[HttpGet]
    public JsonResult MappingExists(int id)
    {
        if (Privileges.HasAccess(User.Identity.Name))
        {
            try
            {
                var map = new Mapping
                {
                    ID = id
                };
                return this.Json("{\"MappingExists\": \"" + map.Exists() + "\"}", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            catch (Exception x)
            {
                return this.Json("{\"Message\": \"Unable to Get Mapping.\"}");
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I put a break point in the very first line of the controller, but it does not get hit.  I get a 500 error in the JS console.  I think the error is thrown because the Response Headers return   text/html; charset=utf-8 while the Request Headers are expecting application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01.

This was working at one point, then all of a sudden it started throwing the 500 error.  Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: What is the repose body from the server? This could be related to an actual server-side error.

Comment: It is a server side issue.  Going directly to the url showed the error was caused from one of the values in the dropdown being sent to the controller was a string and the controller was expecting an integer.  *face-palm*

Comment: your post confuses me. on the one hand the title implies you're getting wrong data back on the other hand your body implies the action method never gets hit.

Comment: Yeah, the action was never getting hit.  I'm not sure why it was telling me that the response header is returning something.  I think it was returning html because it was returning an error.